# Need help, failed to start Lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

I following this tutorial corectly : http://howtoforge.com/installing-lighttpd-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-fedora-14

But now i got this error :

```
    [root@fedora lighttpd]# /etc/init.d/lighttpd start
Starting lighttpd: 2011-03-24 00:06:03: (configfile.c.907) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 326 pos: 92 parser failed somehow near here: include_shell 
                                                           [FAILED]
```

How i can fix this? thanks...

Comment: Since it's something related to the confif file we should read the file content

Comment: Please check this out : http://paste.lighttpd.net/1559

Comment: Lines from 216 to 222 should be uncommented, wipe away the starting pund sign.

Comment: Still not working...


[root@fedora lighttpd]# /etc/init.d/lighttpd start
Starting lighttpd: 2011-03-24 16:55:29: (configfile.c.848) source: find /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 1 pos: 1 invalid character in variable name 
2011-03-24 16:55:29: (configfile.c.904) configfile parser failed at:  
2011-03-24 16:55:29: (configfile.c.907) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 328 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL) 
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: change the last line from

Comment: change the last line into         include "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf" and repost the conf

Comment: still error : 


[root@fedora lighttpd]# /etc/init.d/lighttpd start
Starting lighttpd: 2011-03-24 17:11:28: (configfile.c.953) opening configfile  /etc/lighttpd/find /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf failed: No such file or directory 
2011-03-24 17:11:28: (configfile.c.907) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 328 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL) 


| this is my config : http://paste.lighttpd.net/1560

Comment: Ok. I actually don't know why you (the original conf) should run find on a path... I commented the last line. Try this one: http://paste.lighttpd.net/1561

Comment: Ok... now another error : [root@fedora lighttpd]# /etc/init.d/lighttpd start
Starting lighttpd: 2011-03-24 17:24:42: (network.c.345) can't bind to port:  80 Address already in use 
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: Better. Now the syntax of the config file is correct but the server doesn't start as another process is using the port 80. Maybe are you running an apache instance or maybe you already started lighty :-p Try to visit http://127.0.0.1 and discover what's running

Comment: Ok, it's apache... i've never install apache, maybe it's installed by default. How i can disable it, and let lighttpd start when boot?

Comment: It depends on your distribution. In particular for Fedora core the answer is here: http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/#services

Comment: It's working now.. Thanks David Costa, you help me...  :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make lighty work, starting from this file:
http://paste.lighttpd.net/1559
You have to:

Configuration syntax corrections:

1. Uncomment the PHP-fastcgi section so that it opens and close the right number of parenthesis.
2. Comment the last line which doesn't return valid configuration data + it's a nonsense (to me)

Configure the service to start:

1. On fedora core use its tools to STOP every other service that uses the port 80 tcp (i.e. Apache)
2. Using these tools configure lighttpd as a service to be run on the default runlevel.

A brief explanation about the fedora core service configuration tools can be found here:
http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/#services